# Invalid controller specified (error) - Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I get all the time this error:

> exception 'Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Exception' with message 'Invalid controller specified (error)' in blub\libraries\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php:242

I have a file "ErrorController.php" in the "controllers" directory looking like this:

```
class ErrorController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function errorAction()
    {
        // blub
    }
}
```

My bootstrap looks like this:

```
protected function _initController()
{
    $this->_frontcontroller = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $this->_frontcontroller->setControllerDirectory(APPLICATION_PATH . 'controllers/');
}

protected function _initRoute()
{
    $this->_route = $this->_frontcontroller->getRouter();
    $this->_route->addRoute('default', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
        ':controller/:action/*', array(
            'module'     => 'default',
            'controller' => 'index',
            'action'     => 'index'
        )
    ));
}

public function run()
{
    try {
        $this->_frontcontroller->dispatch();
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        print nl2br($e->__toString());
    }
}
```

*application.ini*

```
[bootstrap]
autoloadernamespaces[] = "Zend_"
autoloadernamespaces[] = "ZendX_"

[production]    
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/libraries"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"

resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.throwexceptions = 0
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0


[development : production]
resources.frontcontroller.params.throwexceptions = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should rely on the resource loader/bootstrap to get your frontController, drop the `_initController()`

To get your controller from the boostrap, you can do `$this->bootstrap('frontController');` and `$frontController = $this->getResource('frontController');`.  This way it will use the configuration in your application.ini.

As far as the error goes, I think your problem might be the missing slash on: `APPLICATION_PATH . '/controllers/'` that you are manually setting in the bootstrap.  Your `APPLICATION_PATH` might not end with a `/`, therefore it can't find `applicationcontrollers/ErrorController.php`

Also, your `_initRoute()` function could be replaced with the following application.ini:

```
resources.router.routes.default.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route"
resources.router.routes.default.route = ":controller/:action/*"
resources.router.routes.default.defaults.controller = "index"
resources.router.routes.default.defaults.action = "index"
resources.router.routes.default.defaults.module = "default"
```

This leaves the only part of your bootstrap that wants the controller the `run()` function's `try{}catch{}` which could be moved to your `index.php` instead.