# Extra folder in controllers in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks

I would like to add a new directory in controllers. I don't want to create a module or something. My structure is like this:

```
application
    controllers
        connections
    models
    ...
```

I would like to be able to add any controller to connections so that I can use it.

Oh and, the controllers inside connections will only be used by

```
// forward to an action in another controller:
// FooController::bazAction(),
// in the current module:
$this->_forward('baz', 'foo', null, array('baz' => 'bogus'));
```

My question is what do I have to add to bootstrap (or anywhere else) to be able to use those controllers?

I keep getting the error message: Invalid Controller

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276094/invalid-controller-specified-error-zend-framework

Comment: That's not really helping. I don't want to have just one controller in that directory. I want to have many and not have to add each and every one to the route manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the following structure:

```
application
    controllers
        Connection  (with a capitalized C and no S)
    models
    ...
```

You may forward to the controller using:

```
// forward to an action in another controller:
// Connection_FooController::bazAction(),
// in the current module:
$this->_forward('baz', 'connection_foo', null, array('baz' => 'bogus'));
```

Comment: Oh my god. I've tried everything except to write connection with capital C. Thanks. It works